# Casting Base class object pointer to Derived class object pointer without using dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, rtti

Because of the performance issue, I am not allowed to use `dynamic_cast` or `virtual function`. Now, I need to get the child object from the parent class pointer passed to a function. The information about which child object it points to is not available. Dynamic cast would have solved this issue if it was allowed to use.

As a workaround, I am currently storing an enum containing the type information about the child object in the base class. Once we receive the base class pointer, I fetch the type of derived class object it is pointing to form the value stored in the enum and then do a `static_cast` on it.
I know it's not a proper solution. Is there any scenario it could fail? Also is there any other solution?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
enum class Type{
    Derived1,
    Derived2
};

class Base{
    public:
    Type type;
    Base(){};
    Base(Type t){type = t;}
    void print(){cout<<"in Base"<<endl;}
};

class Derived1: public Base{
    public:
    Derived1():Base(Type::Derived1){}
    void print(){cout<<"in Derived1"<<endl;}
    void run(){cout<<"in Derived1"<<endl;}
};

class Derived2: public Base{
    public:
    Derived2():Base(Type::Derived2){}
    void print(){cout<<"in Derived2"<<endl;}
    void run(){cout<<"in Derived2"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Base* a = new Derived1();
    Derived1* b;
    if(a->type == Type::Derived1){
        b= static_cast<Derived1*>(a);
    }
    b->print();  \\in Derived2
    b->run();    \\in Derived2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who forbid you to use standard polymorphism and virtual functions? Have they (or you) measured that it really is a *major* bottleneck in the application? Unless they have numbers to back up that claim, I would contest that.

Comment: You may wanna have a look at CRTP https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/

Comment: I'm surprised that whoever doesn't let you use `dynamic_cast` or virtual functions lets you add a type tag. (This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), by the way. If you said *why* you need to do this, you might get an answer that helps you not need it, and that's a much better solution.)

Comment: @molbdnilo As I said this is not the final solution. This is just one of the workaround I thought of.

Comment: Looks OK to me, you can gain some performance here at a cost. However, it's upto your code owner to decide.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the methods these objects are associated with can get called thousands of times per second. For example, 100k call takes 145ms, we are trying to minimize it further. And I guess getting rid of vtable and rtti baggage will help. Not sure about the number or whether adding type enum to base class would defeat the purpose. Will try to get the numbers.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude This is exactly what Herb Sutter was talking about in his keynote at CppCon, it comes to a cost, there are compilers that actually are able to disable your feature and you can write a better version by hand.